# Flag SDL_HWPALETTE not recognized by gcc

Tags: c, sdl

The flag `SDL_HWPALETTE` is being marked as undeclared in gcc, even though SDL is properly included (many SDL functions and such are being used fine).  Do i need to include something other then `sdl.h` to use `SDL_HWPALETTE`?

I checked out the docs for `SDL_SetVideoMode`, the function that uses this flag, and nothing about declaring or additional includes was mentioned for `SDL_HWPALETTE` was mentioned, and I'm certain i didn't typo.

**Code snipet**:

```
#include "SDL2/SDL.h"
screen = SDL_SetVideoMode(640, 480, 0, SDL_HWPALETTE);
```

**Error Output**:

```
In function 'init':
error: 'SDL_HWPALETTE' undeclared
```

Comment: you should add more tags. This is about SDL usage, so add the tags that describe your problem. Write a minimal verfiable example.

Comment: See, @ChrisBeck was able to answer you, because he knew you used "SDL2/SDL.h". Without your info, this would have been harder to spot.

Comment: yeah, thanks for the tip @MarcusMüller

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using SDL2, SDL_SetVideoMode was removed and so was this enum.

More info here: https://forums.libsdl.org/viewtopic.php?t=9163&sid=23359eedacf25591f8fe7c3423342de4

> In SDL 2 you need to create a window and a renderer. Check out the
>   headers and/or docs.
>
> Regards,
>
> Leszek

Comment: @user3250420 np bro :p